# regex to allow 0-5 group list of numbers (int or decimal) separated by |

Tags: javascript, html, regex

I have a regular expression that allow integers and/or decimal

```
var reg = /^((\s*)|([0-9]\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?%?$))$/.;
```

How do I allow users to enter 0 to 5 groups of integers and/or decimals **separated** by **|**.

**Update:**

this should match:

```
5.01|76543|23343|4.32323|3
```

these examples should not match :

```
5.01,543,2343 
1|2|3|4|5|6
```

Comment: Can you provide examples of what should and shouldn't match?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could try:

```
^((\s*)|([0-9]\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?%?))*(\|((\s*)|([0-9]\d{0,9}(\.\d{1,3})?%?))+){0,4}$
```

check it here https://regexr.com/40m7h

Comment: @sal you are welcome , i appreciate set it to correct if it meets your need.

Answer (score 1):

To match  0 to 5 groups, you could match an optional first group followed by repeating a pipe and and one or more digits 0 - 4 times.

`^(?:\d+(?:\.\d+)?)?(?:\|\d+(?:\.\d+)?){0,4}$`

[Regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/lr4XY1/1)

**Explanation**

- `^` Assert the strart of the string
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\d+(?:\.\d+)?` match one or more times a digit followed by an optional part that matches a dot and a digit
- `)?` Close non capturing group and make it optional
- `(?:` Non capturing group

  - `\|\d+(?:\.\d+)?` Match a `|` followed by matching a digit and an optional part that matches a dot and a digit
- `){0,4}` Close non capturing group and repeat that 0-4 times
- `$` Assert end of the string.

Comment: what is different between this and other answer? it seems both working. thank you for answer.

Comment: People find different regex solutions that usually have varying computation times. It's possible that a problem requiring a regex is heavily dependent on computation time.

Comment: thank you so much. it's really complete explanation.i learned to much today

Comment: @sal You are welcome. The first answer has a lot of optional parts which increases the backtracking.

Answer (score 0):

`^(\d+(\.\d+)?\|){0,4}(\d+(\.\d+)?)?$`

Explanation:

```
^          | Assert beginning of string
(          | Match the following group:
  \d+      |   One or more consecutive digits
  (\.\d+)? |   A group containing "." and one or more digits (optional)
  \|       |   A "|" character
){0,4}     | Close group; match zero to four of these
(          | Match the following group:
  \d+      |   One or more consecutive digits
  (\.\d+)? |   A group containing "." and one or more digits (optional)
)?         | Close group; matching is optional
$          | Assert end of string
```

#### [Try it here](https://regex101.com/r/Z1d5ZW/2)

Comment: I think that always requires 1 group to match.

Comment: Overlooked the zero-length requirement. Updated.